# assert macro that prints the values which are passed in

Tags: c, macros, assert, c-preprocessor

In our C codebase we have assertion macros such as:

```
ASSERT3(x, ==, y)      // x=0, y=1 results in "main.c:45: 'x == y' (0 == 1) is untrue"
ASSERT(x == y)         // x=0, y=1 results in "main.c:45: 'x == y' is untrue"
```

Clearly, the `ASSERT3` form is much more helpful when you're trying to debug something after a failure because it tells you what the values of the variables were.

However, whenever you need to do a more complex assertion (especially those including `||` since you can just split the ones with `&&` into multiple assertions), like `ASSERT(x == y || y != 0 || x == 2)`, you can no longer take advantage of the awesome `ASSERT3` format. Clearly, I *could* build a macro like `ASSERT11(x, ==, y, ||, y, !=, 0, ||, x, ==, 2)`, but ideally I'd like to create a single macro which can handle a variable number of arguments and figure out what to print on its own. To do this, I think I'd need the macro to filter out arguments which are just logical operators so that it doesn't try to print their values -- is there any way to do that?

Comment: Even with a simple `x == y` kind of expression, how can you print `x` and `y` without knowing what types are involved?  Printing the whole expression (as a string) and the result (true/false) is easy, but printing the values of the variables involved will differ depending on the types.

Comment: Simply do assert(x == y && "X different from Y"); Prepare a string using sprintf and use this in the expression.

Comment: I see you problem, the string expression I would and with the expr for assertion is non-const

Comment: @Dmitri I skimmed over a detail: this is kernel programming, so almost all variables are integers or pointers -- we simply cast to `unsigned long long` and print the result in hex.

Comment: [doctest](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest) has [Expression decomposing asserts](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest/blob/master/doc/markdown/assertions.md#expression-decomposing-asserts) that can also be used [outside of a testing context](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest/blob/master/doc/markdown/assertions.md#using-asserts-out-of-a-testing-context). AFAICT they cannot handle expressions as complex as your disjunction example, but they could replace your `ASSERT3` macro.

Answer (score 0):

I've had that feeling and thought along those lines, but it turns out that asserts are for things that should never happen, so it doesn't really make sense to have fancy output for them. What you're looking for is a debugging message that's printed when those conditions are not met, so you should code it that way:

```
if (!condition) {
    DEBUG(whatever); /* or however your ASSERT() macro prints */
    PANIC();         /* or however your ASSERT() macro aborts */
}
```

In this case, I actually think that code would be easier to write, far easier to read, and significantly more reliable than the complicated ASSERT statement you're going to end up with. Not to mention that once the assert gets that complicated, surely there's other important relevant information around that isn't actually in the assert statement, anyway.

Comment: On the contrary, when these "should never happen" conditions do occur, I find you frequently want all the output you can get to help you debug. Usually we also get a core dump on assertion failures, but picking through that just to get a couple of variable values takes a lot longer than reading them directly from a debug string. (Analyzing core dumps to get variable values is especially a pain due to the debugger we use, but that's a separate problem.)

Comment: As I say, what you want is debugging messages. A fine approach to the problem you're explaining is adding debugging messages to asserts: ASSERT_MSG(condition, "a=%d b=%d", a, b). The mistake I was commenting on was trying to make the assert itself a debugging message.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not worth the effort that you would have to put into it, but I'll give you the general outline and you can decide.

It can theoretically be done with a variadic macro

```
#define UBER_ASSERT(...) uberAssert( __FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__ )
```

and a variadic function

```
void uberAssert( char *filename, int linenumber, char *format, ... )
```

Typical usage would look like this

```
UBER_ASSERT( "%1d == %2d || %2d != 0 || %1d == 2", x, y );
```

and a minimal example would look like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define UBER_ASSERT(...) uberAssert( __FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__ )

int evaluateExpression( char *format, va_list args )
{
    int x = va_arg( args, int );
    int y = va_arg( args, int );
    printf( "evaluating \"%s\" with x=%d y=%d\n", format, x, y );
    return 0;
}

void displayExpression( char *format, va_list args )
{
    int x = va_arg( args, int );
    int y = va_arg( args, int );
    printf( "%s with x=%d y=%d\n", format, x, y );
}

void uberAssert( char *filename, int linenumber, char *format, ... )
{
    va_list args, args2;

    va_start( args, format );
    va_copy( args2, args );
    if ( !evaluateExpression( format, args ) )
    {
        printf( "%s:%d: ", filename, linenumber );
        displayExpression( format, args2 );
        abort();
    }
    va_end( args );
    va_end( args2 );
}

int main( void )
{
    int x = 3;
    int y = 5;
    UBER_ASSERT( "%1d==%2d || %2d!=0 || %1d==2", x, y );
}
```

The hard part is to write the expression evaluator and the expression display function, and that I leave as an exercise for the reader.